# Big Query Table Creation Confusion

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to create a big query table with the schema as follows

```
snippet:STRING,comment_date:TIMESTAMP
```

And i have data as follows

```
"Love both of these brands , but the "" buy a $100k car , get or give a pair of $40 shoes "" message seems .",2015-06-22 00:00:00

"All Givens Best Commercial Ever",2015-06-22 00:00:00
```

I was confused because both the rows were accepted and were inserted in the table although in the first line all the snippet string is in between the double quotes but it also contains double quotes and comma in between

Why does not big query get confused there ?

Comment: It is a good idea to get your data as clean and regular as you can.  [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) is a loose standard for CSV files, specifying among other things that commas are OK in quoted fields and that quotes within a field should be doubled. Correct parsing is often 1 char at a time. And uglier CSV files do **not** follow it, inventing or ignoring important stuff like quote-escapes as they go along.  The average programmer or analyst tasked to quickly parse a CSV will split CSV data on comma, which will be incorrect with  commas in quoted fields or quote-escapes.

Comment: Thanks @Paul i did not knew this. That means big query is handling it as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing CSV, BigQuery splits only on unquoted commas, and it treats double quotes `""` as a single escaped quote character `"` when encountered inside a quoted string. So your input is valid CSV according to BigQuery.

Comment: What if i had a new line inside the string ? Then I need some work around.

Comment: Can u suggest something

Comment: If you set the allowQuotedNewlines flag, then you can include newline characters inside quoted CSV strings. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.allowQuotedNewlines